# Cassandra and querying hierarchies

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hierarchical-data, composite-key

I am investigating Cassandra, but cannot find an answer in any documentation to the following.

I need to query ranges across a deep hierarchy. I have determined that the easiest way to represent the hierarchy is to have each level as a column. For example:

```
Origin           Manufacturer    Price    ID
Europe.Germany   VW Group.Audi   20000    1
Europe.Germany   VW Group.Porshe 21000    2
Europe.Germany   BMW             19000    3
```

Here is a pseudo SQL example:

```
SELECT ID FROM CompositeTable WHERE (Origin STARTS WITH 'Europe')
AND (Manufacturer STARTS WITH 'VW Group' AND IS NOT 'VW Group.Porshe' OR IS 'BMW')
AND (Price BETWEEN 18000 AND 22000)
```

Result:

```
ID = [1, 3]
```

Can Cassandra perform this type of search across a composite index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composite Keys in Cassandra is a kind of `multiple-column index` in DBMS, where if you have index on c1, c2 and c3 in a table with columns from c1 to c6. DB will always try to use you index if the query is for `=, > , <, >=, <=` operation on (c1), (c1,c2) or (c1, c2, c3) but not for (c2), (c2, c3), (c3) or (c1, c3). The case is the same in cassandra but here you have multiple-column index on c1 to c6 [since the columns are sorted first based on c1 and the collision carries over to c2 and follows on]

Comment: Ok, so a) Cassandra does support composite indexes via secondary indexes? and b) will it support range queries across those columns? Some mature DBs don't even support the latter.

Comment: I checked the Datastax documentation, and there is no mention of composite indexes. However, it also doesn't mention composite keys, which certainly do exist. Is my scenario a good case for composite keys?

Comment: See secondary indexes are totally different from composite keys. Basically in cassandra you can't filter columns based on their values. Inorder to achieve that, you need to create secondary index over the column . But composite keys is different. It is a struct which helps to achieve indexing automagically with no effort but just by modelling data

Comment: Ok, so a composite key is my solution it seems.

Comment: It might be a solution incase you are understanding it properly :P Because all it can give u is `*, a:* or a:b:* or a:b:c:* or a:b:c:d` incase you have a composite key of a:b:c:d. * can be a point query or equality condn and every thing is related to column name not their values :D

Comment: What do you mean it's related to the column name, not their values? I understand the following: Cassandra can create a composite clustered index in the same way SQL Server does, and that one can query <=> across each column's values. Right?

Comment: I also understand that all the logical rows with the same partition key get stored as a single physical “wide row.”

Comment: Nooooo It doesn't create any index at all. Since the column names are by default sorted by their name [not by their value] henec they almost act like an index. But you can't assume that index is on its value. Incase you need that you should prefer secondary indexes. Please read this http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1

Comment: Actually a lot has changed after cql 3.0 is launched in cassandra composite types. So, I might even be outdated :D

Comment: Ok, I got you. It's on the column name, not value. So then my final question is directly as follows: will secondary indexes efficiently be able to handle the query I state in my original question?

Comment: How does one perform not equal against a column name (as value)?

Comment: I finally installed Cassandra 1.2 (and Fluentcassandra for C#), and unfortunately this does not work. It's demanding equality comparators. I tried the columns in and out of the PK.