# Filtering columns in Cassandra 1.1 - repeat & clarification

Tags: database, cassandra, primary-key, filtering

I have asked this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297841/cassandra-1-1-composite-keys-columns-and-filtering-in-cql-3), and have received apparently conflicting answers from various sources, including documentation. So I am repeating it with links to documentation and what some people at Datastax have said, in the hopes that a developer of Cassandra (or someone with real Cassandra 1.1 experience) can clear this up for me.

I wish to run queries as follows, where ID is the PK, and Data is the final "value":

```
SELECT Data FROM MyApp.ProductFamilies WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?) AND PriceLow >= ? 
AND PriceHigh <= ? AND MassLow >= ? AND MassHigh <= ? and MnfGeo >= ? AND 
MnfGeo <= ?
```

Note that under the hood, CQL is filtering the column names, which are the values. I'm not filtering the final "value", and hence need no secondary index.

[This documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/SELECT) states the following:

> WHERE clauses can include greater-than and less-than comparisons on
>   columns other than the first. As long as all previous key-component
>   columns have already been identified with strict = comparisons, the
>   last given key component column can be any sort of comparison.

Per this, the above query would work fine, and @jbellis confirmed this, but others said no because of the PK arrangement.

The statement is a bit vague because column 1 may or may not be the full PK, hence is not intrinsically significant. I interpret it to read:

1. You can <=> query all non PK columns.
2. If you have a composite key, and you have an = on each component except the final one, you can <=> query the last component.

However, per the following, one cannot apply a WHERE clause on a column that is not part of the PK ([see here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections#comment-120658)).

> The problem with doing a CONTAINS without an index is that this is
>   very inefficient in general, and forbidding such generally inefficient
>   query is something we want with Cassandra/CQL (much like the fact that
>   we don’t allow ‘WHERE a = 3′ unless a is either part of the PK or is
>   indexed).

Per this, we can apply a WHERE predicate only to PK components. This means my query won't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: It sounds like you're at the point where you should just try it.

Comment: I can't argue that. I just wanted to make sure it will do what I want before diving into the world of getting a Java app running :))

Comment: @jbellis I tried the query per the answer you gave (which I ref. to here), and it doesn't work. It's demanding equality.