# Is it possible to search second component of composite column with phpcassa for cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra, phpcassa

so, I have:

```
$sys->create_column_family($keyspace, 'MYCF', array(
    "column_type" => "Super",
    "comparator_type" => "CompositeType(TimeUUIDType, UTF8Type)",
    "key_validation_class" => "UTF8Type"
));
```

Inserted few records and they can be retrieved correctly (auto sorted by timeuuid which is what I wanted). For example, to get last one this is working as expected:

```
$slice = new ColumnSlice('', '', $count=1, $reversed=true);
```

Is it possible to get for instance last one with specific second component (ex. "TWITTER")?

Tried like this but no luck (NotFoundException):

```
$slice = new ColumnSlice(array(array(null, array("TWITTER", true))), '', $count=1, $reversed=true);
```

Tried with '' instead of null, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297841/cassandra-1-1-composite-keys-columns-and-filtering-in-cql-3 Check this out

Comment: Also this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&hl=en#!topic/phpcassa/kxNNRD_4S-A